# Google App Engine app.yaml handler for PHP file

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, routes, app.yaml

I have a Codeigniter site deployed to Google App Engine PHP 7 environment.  I then added a simple PHP file named `hello.php`:

```
<?php
  echo "Hello World";
?>
```

and placed it in the site root like this:

```
Root
--application
--css
--js
--system
--hello.php
```

When I access `hello.php` from the Cloud Shell localhost, it loads perfectly:

`https://8080-dot-1234567-dot-devshell.appspot.com/hello.php`

When I access `hello.php` after being deployed to Google App Engine I get `404 Page Not Found` error.  Since GAE does not support `.htaccess` files, I understand that the correct way to handle the routing would be through the `app.yaml` file.  Here is my `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: php72

handlers:
- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /images
  static_dir: images   

- url: .*
  script: auto
```

All of the assets in the js, css and images folders are accessible over GAE, but `hello.php` is not accessible.  How should I modify this `app.yaml` file so that the routing will serve up the `hello.php` file on GAE?

Comment: Which is your `app.yaml` location relative to the site dir structure you mentioned? It *should* be side by side with your `hello.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce your issue and discovered that the error seems to be related with the name of your php file.

As mentioned in the app.yaml [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref) the script field defines the entrypoint of your application but the only allowed value is “auto”, GAE will look for a controller at index.php or public/index.php and because yours is named hello.php GAE is unable to find it. Just change the name of the file and it will work.

Hope this helps.